# Generating different class vectors with one function

Tags: r, function, if-statement, case-when

```
DV<-DV %>%
      mutate(outcome_diff=case_when(
  is.numeric(outcome) ~ outcome1-outcome2
  is.factor(outcome) ~ ifelse(outcome1==outcome2,"agree","disagree"), 
  IV$outcome==NA|IV$outcome2==NA ~NA_character_,  
  TRUE ~ NA_character_))
```

In the previous code, we successed to make a loop to generatate many outcomes. for each outcome, we generate outcome1 and outcome2.

In the presented code,  What I tried to do was

1. if the outcome variable is numeric, generate outcome_diff variable by (outcome1-outcome2)
2. if the outcome variables is factors,  do this: (ifelse(outcome1==outcome2, "agree","disagree").

However, I faced a problem that NA_character_ generates errors.
Moreover, I guess case_When() function does not like to deal with different class vectors.

is there any better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. is `IV` a completely different data.frame than `DV`?

Comment: To test for NA, use is.na(). Nothing else will work as expected, including is.numeric() or x == NA.